# What was the intuition from the Typescript Team to make not === default

Tags: javascript, typescript, coding-style

Since Typescript is a type safe language why `==` still exist? Is there a reason for it?

Comment: Really it does not try to be a different language? Defiantly Typescript is a different language in comparison.. @httpdigest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you should avoid `==` there is even a tslint [rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/triple-equals/) in this regard. There are some valid use cases around `null` and `undefined` equality, namely `null == undefined` while  `null !== undefined` so if you use `===` you need to check for both `undefined` and `null` in cases where a value is missing (as both `null` and `undefined` can be used for missing) which is inconvenient.

As far as the reasoning behind keeping it, I think the defining line from their site says it best "Typescript is a typed **superset** of JavaScript" so everything from Javascript was kept just augmented with types, including `==`

Comment: What are the valid use cases ? Can you edit your answer ? :)

Comment: @BilalReffas Added usage

Comment: Thant you so much :)